# How to recover files from corrupted fat32 USB disk

Tags: 16.04, mount, data-corruption

The drive was working normally until yesterday. Today when tyring to mount from Thunar it says:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdd1 at /media/myname/ARCH_201511: 
Command-line 
`mount -t "iso9660" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,mode=0400,dmode=0500" "/dev/sdd1" "/media/myname/ARCH_201511"'
exited with non-zero exit status 32: 
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdd1,

missing codepage or helper program, or other error

In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
dmesg | tail or so.
```

I mabe a backup with: `ddrescue -f -n /dev/sdd backup.img rescue.log`

**$ dmesg**

```
[ 4303.845743] usb 2-1.5: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
[ 4303.961832] usb 2-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387
[ 4303.961837] usb 2-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 4303.961839] usb 2-1.5: Product: Mass Storage
[ 4303.961841] usb 2-1.5: Manufacturer: Generic
[ 4303.961843] usb 2-1.5: SerialNumber: 2D9FF525
[ 4303.962201] usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 4303.962355] scsi host4: usb-storage 2-1.5:1.0
[ 4304.979880] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 4304.980361] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[ 4304.981562] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] 3915776 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 GB/1.87 GiB)
[ 4304.982702] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 4304.982706] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[ 4304.983834] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 4304.989441]  sdd: sdd1
[ 4304.992906] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 4310.608865] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
[ 4315.815846] ISOFS: Unable to identify CD-ROM format.
```

**$ lsblk**

```
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdd              8:48   1   1,9G  0 disk  
└─sdd1           8:49   1   1,9G  0 part
```

**$ fdisk -l /dev/sdd**

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 1,9 GiB, 2004877312 bytes, 3915776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x687bd47c

Device     Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 3915775 3913728  1,9G  b W95 FAT32
```

**$ mmls backup.img**

```
DOS Partition Table
Offset Sector: 0
Units are in 512-byte sectors

      Slot      Start        End          Length       Description
000:  Meta      0000000000   0000000000   0000000001   Primary Table (#0)
001:  -------   0000000000   0000002047   0000002048   Unallocated
002:  000:000   0000002048   0003915775   0003913728   Win95 FAT32 (0x0b)
```

**$ mmls /dev/sdd1**

```
Cannot determine partition type
```

**$ dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v /dev/sdd**

```
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Logical sector size (37008 bytes) is not a multiple of the physical sector size.
```

**$ dosfsck -w -r -l -a -v /dev/sdd1**

```
fsck.fat 3.0.28 (2015-05-16)
Logical sector size is zero.
```

**How can i recover a file from this drive?**

Comment: @SorenA Tried with -t vfat. Got same message.

Comment: Maybe you can try according to the tips in the following link, [Repair the partition table and file system of a pendrive](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2196858&p=13409986#post13409986). The methods work on 'any mass storage device' for example a hard disk drive. If the files are very valuable, please consider cloning to another drive with `ddrescue` and to do the repair/recovery work on the cloned copy.

Comment: I’m not putting this as an answer because I’m unclear as to whether or not it’s recognized as device even if it doesn’t mount. Check out the program testdisk it’s very good for recovering files I’ve used it on drives that wouldn’t mount and filesystems that were totally wrecked. If it works let me know and I’ll put it up as an answer.

Comment: @Afflicted The device is recognized. Can't mount it. I was able to Make a clone.img and extract some files with foremost. But foremost hangs after some seconds. The recovered files, unfortunately, don't include the file I'm worried about.

Comment: Why would you use **-r** (*interactively repair the filesystem*) and **-a** (*automatically repair the filesystem*) together on dosfsck?